# My discord.js bot is not responding when i made changes to this, i am still new, but i cant see whats wrong

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

Heres the code,

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Keyv = require('keyv');
const client = new Discord.Client()
const prefixes = new Keyv();
const prefix = '/';
const eris = require('eris')

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on('message',async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    let args;
    // handle messages in a guild
    if (message.guild) {
        let prefix;

        // if we found a prefix, setup args; otherwise, this isn't a command
        if (!prefix) return;
        args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    } else {
        // handle DMs
        const slice = message.content.startsWith(prefix) ? prefix.length : 0;
        args = message.content.slice(slice).split(/ +/);
    }

    // get the first space-delimited argument after the prefix as the command
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === 'args-info') {
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
        }

        message.channel.send(`Command name: ${command}\nArguments: ${args}`);
    }
  
    if (command === 'ping') {
        return message.channel.send('Pong!')
    }
    if ( command === 'help'){
        return message.channel.send('Sorry! I have no commands yet. You can use /ping to make me reply "Pong!"')
    }
    if(message === '(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻'){
        return message.channel.send('(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ yo face.')  
    }
    if(message === '┬─┬ ノ( ゜-゜ノ)') return message.reply('thanks for returning the table.')
  
    if(command === 'about') return message.channel.send('Creator: mudkip989, Version: 1.0.0, Name: ' +  client.user.tag)
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

I've tested and the bot is online, and I've used simpler code that worked, but when I have this, It just doesn't work. I don't understand why. I've made changes and maybe I need to understand more of the "rules" or thing that wont work of discord bot code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (message.guild) {
        let prefix;

        // if we found a prefix, setup args; otherwise, this isn't a command
        if (!prefix) return;
```

It looks like all you're doing right here is declaring a variable called `prefix` and then checking if its value is falsy. This will always evaluate to true since the value of `prefix` is undefined.

Its also important to point out that your `let prefix;` is shadowing your global const with the same name.